# cant get the wizard to install Hero CMS of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to install hero CMS of codeigniter user guide says to go to mysite/install then i will find installation wizard (if server requirements are ok)...
While doing so I found no wizard it just shows index.php 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should change config/config.example.php to config/config.php and check the .htaccess file exist or not. Then enter mysite/install.

If this is not working, activate the display errors in config file or in default controller and check what error it shows.

It is got installed in my system and working fine.

Also you need to give permissions to the required files or directories